# how to solve this differential equation $(\sin y+2x\cos^2 y)\ dx+x\cos y(2x \sin y+1)\ dy=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

This is my first question here. I tried to solve this ODE.

$$\left(\sin(y)+2x \cos^2(y)\right) \mathrm{d}x + x\cos(y) \left(2x \sin(y)+1\right) \mathrm{d}y = 0$$

Any suggestion?

Comment: Consider $x\sin y + x^2 \cos ^2 y + c=0$. On differentiation, this will give $(\sin y + 2x\cos^2 y)dx + (x\sin y - 2x^2 \cos y \sin y)dy$,   which is pretty close to your given equation. Maybe a little modification will do the trick. Also, I arrived at this via brute force (aka "observation"). Also, if by chance you made a mistake in reading the question, it might even solve your problem.

Comment: @Tineo :there is a typo of sign in your ODE.